# What is the best way to implement 'Excel like column sizing' for an HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table, asp.net-2.0, column-width, column-sizing

I want to allow the user to resize columns in an HTML table, using the same method as you would in Excel.  Drag the space between columns and size.

I did some research on this last year, and found a few hacks and kludges.  Most were pretty bad, and I didn't find anything really good.  Now, it looks like I need to implement this functionality, and want to do it right, so before I start this again, I just thought I'd ask if anybody else has done this, and how they did it.

I believe I've seen a FogBugz demo video where they had this implemented.  So I know it can be done well.

BTW-I'd prefer not to use any open source frameworks, since my client may sell this app in the future.

Comment: Using an open source framework does not preclude your client from selling the product in the future. You should read up on licensing.

Comment: You are absolutely correct ... I should.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458479/where-can-i-find-an-authoritative-overview-of-open-source-licences  This is something I need enlightenment with.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a html grid myself in the past and having done so my best advice would be: use someone else's.

I've looked at this jquery grid control in the past but have never got around to trying it out:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs spreadsheet application does what you are looking for.  That may be worth looking at, but their code is very dense.

Answer (score 0):

The extjs framework provides the functionality you need.  I can not tell (I am no lawyer) whether their license is suitable for your customer or not.  However, it appears possible for you to purchase a license from them which allows you to not have to publish your customers code as open source.  This may suffice.

I would suggest that you develop your application using extjs in parallel with investigating the license.  if the licensing suits your customer, you're done, and you win by using a stable and high-quality platform.  If your can't make the license work for your customer, then you have to port to something else, but at least you will already have a high quality first prototype to work from, so the effort to produce the product will be less.  And meanwhile you have a very nice prototype while refining the interface